# Android Studio BUILD FAILED duplicate entry: com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.class

Tags: java, android, gradle, duplicates

I had the following error, when I was trying to generate my aplication APK.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.class

It appeared after I had added: " multiDexEnabled true "
to my gradle file. But it's necessary.

Anyone can help me?

The gradle file contains this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"


    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.nowakprojects.socialmafia"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'boolean', 'PREMIUM_VERSION', PremiumVersionBoolean
     }
}

ext {
    JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    DAGGER_VERSION = '2.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5' //Parceler - przenoszenie obiektow miedzy Activity
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0' //ButterKnife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0' //EventBus
    compile 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.3' //SeekBar
   // compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.4'
    //compile "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2"
}
```

Comment: I answered this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462608/program-type-already-present-com-google-thirdparty-publicsuffix/54928847#54928847

Answer (score -1):

This issue is because of `compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'` gradle.

> Just remove the `compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'`, it
>    will work.

Don't know the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @Mat he's kind of right, you should have parceler in your app, that module should be an `apt`/`annotationProcessor` entry. Same with `butterkninfe-compiler`.